# ATK4 How change view

Tags: atk4

....Views can have a default template or it can be specified or inherited. For example - default template of Api class is "shared.html" - that's where your header/footer is....

How or where can I change default view/template from shared.html e.g. to (3-columns-layout, 2-columns-layout, 1-columns-layout).html?

Comment: Stika, if the answer is OK, could you "accept" it by clicking on checkbox?

Comment: I just wanted to add note, that this will probably change in 4.1. It has now support for 960gs system, which means you can define layout through CSS. This will be documented.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine a function called defaultTemplate() in api and return the name of a new file. Normally when you do that you also add some logic based on page names. Below is example

```
function defaultTemplate(){
    if($this->page=='index')return array('index');
    return array('shared');
}
```

If you need to use columns, look into 'View/Columns' class.